# how to divide css grid like first column 50%, second column 50% and third column 100%?

Tags: html, css

```html
    .main-dev {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    }
```

I want to arrange my grid into 50% 50% and 100% structures. I have attached the required output image.

Current output :

[image: Grid in four box]

Expected Output :

[image: Grid device in 50% 50% and 100%]

Comment: Show the HTML you want to use. Also, don't use percentages to define your grid. Work with `fr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main-dev {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  /* or grid-column: 1 / span 2 */
}
```

```html
<div class="main-dev">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
```

Comment: I used grid-template-columns: 50% 50%; but got a problem when using a column-gap since it still insisted on 50% of the width. I changed to grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; and it seems to account for the gap. As connexo also mentions above.

Comment: @Janspeed Thanks, I edited my answer. It's better for when we want to use some gap.

Comment: Instead of `grid-column: 1 / 3`, prefer `1 / -1`. That expands full-width irrespective of the count of columns!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```css
.item3 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So. Let's imagine you have 3 items with class names `item1`, `item2`, `item3`.

Here is the `style` for them:

```
.item1 { grid-area: item1; }
.item2 { grid-area: item2; }
.item3 { grid-area: item3; }

div{
     display: grid;
     grid-template-areas:
       'item1 item2'
       'item3 item3'
     grid-gap: 10px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you can use `col-`. Here is my example:

```css
.red{
border: 1px solid red;
height:200px;
}

.col-6{
float:left;
width:50%;
}
.col-12{
float:left;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="col-6">
    <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
    <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
    <div class="red"></div>
    </div>


</body>
```

And you can modify the code as you like.

Comment: This question is about CSS grid, not about hacky floats we used to do back in 2007.